# Can you remove competitors listing from google maps?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I'm just having a look at the Google Maps Javascript API and I have a question.

Can I remove competitors from being listed on my map, and only show the business I want to show ?

I'd only want to show The Pinned Business is this possible ?

[image]

Comment: Without seeing your code that's hard to answer.

Comment: This one here is just an iframe that I shared from google, I have the javascript api here http://mrjf-pi.ddns.net/googlemaps.html working

Comment: Just put the relevant bit of the code into the question.

Comment: easiest hack, I would suggest using a layer to overlay your competitor's, use a polygon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can disable the POI

```
            var mlwStyles =[
                {
                    featureType: "poi",
                    elementType: "labels",
                    stylers: [
                          { visibility: "off" }
                    ]
                }
            ];
            var mapOptions = {
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(yourInitLat, yourInitLng),
                zoom: yourInitZoom,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE,
                mapTypeControl:false,
                scaleControl: true, 
                styles: mlwStyles                   
            };
```

Comment: Cheers worked a charm, tried a polygon also which also works, but you'll need several to hide the competitors.

Comment: If you only want to select business points, you can use "poi.business" according to https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/style-reference#style-features

Comment: It's probably worth noting that by toggling visibility of poi (or indeed poi.business) labels, you will also be toggling visibility of the label on your own pin, although it will still be the most obvious, centered pin. The trade-off may or may not be worth it.